# Why is koa-pug throwing "ctx.render is not a function" when using koa-mount

Tags: koa

I have a gist for a simple [Koa server](https://gist.github.com/jrgleason/f9a6dba2a3784e8b504a7623085ffa88) using koa-pug. The working one seems to host the pug file just fine, however, the fail one, which uses koa-mount to forward the app to the root works fine when setting the body but throws

> TypeError: ctx.render is not a function

If I change it to something like

```
ctx.body = "index";
```

It works fine. Why can't I use koa-pug with koa-mount? Or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to assign Pug to the main app and not the route one...

```
 this.app = new Koa();
 this.pug = new Pug({
     app: this.app,
     viewPath: './src/views'
 });
```

Then everything worked great.